# Can I suppress a public bean property in Spring RESTful MVC JSON serialization?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have s simple Java bean class without any annotations or configuration that is being serialized to JSON by Spring RESTful MVC (also without any configuration, just the defaults that come with Spring Boot).

Everything works fine, except that I have a few public convenience getters that calculate some derived properties that I don't want to have included in the JSON.

What is the best way to suppress a single property from JSON serialization?

Comment: You can try adding `@JsonIgnore` to the getter method of the property you are trying to suppress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which parser your application is using under the hood. Most probably it's Jackson and adding `@JsonIgnore` annotation to the attribute should work.

Comment: Spring MVC uses Jackson library.

Comment: @Manish It does by default.

Comment: Thanks, works for me (as I mentioned I did not configure anything, just use the Spring Boot defaults).